# How to enable "Featured Article" on the main page? Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I want to display a random article and a random image once a day on the front page. Like on Wikipedia.

I installed the "FeaturedFeeds" extension, checked if it was enabled, and created the "MediaWiki:Ffeed-*-page", as described in the manual. Replacing "*" with my name. My page is called "MediaWiki:Ffeed-MainFeed-page". However, I don't understand what to do next. The page is empty.
I understand that I need to create some kind of template and put it on the main page, but I don’t understand what exactly to write in the template.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's an easy way to do it. Wikipedia's main page features are prepared manually - there is a set of hand-written featured blurbs, like [Wikipedia:Today's featured article/November 1, 2022](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Today%27s_featured_article/November_1,_2022), and a template on the main page selects the one for today's date. See the links [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template:Main_Page_topics) for more information. FeaturedFeeds just generates an RSS feed from the contents of a given page / set of pages.